# 2 level file loop with variable

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, vbscript, each

I am new to VBS and I am trying to do something I am not sure how.
First level:
I have a set of varible names(strVar()) that I want to use them to 1 check to see if the folder exsists and then if they do not exsits create a folder

```
strVar(0) = "AA
strVar(1) = "AB"
strVar(2) = "AK"

strRootFolder = "C:\IN\ED\Dat\" & strVar
strSourceFolder = X:\\IN\ED\Dat\" & strVar
```

Once the File structure is there as shown in strRootFolder I need to put another folder in each of those folders called "CAL"

So my file structure for example would be-

```
"C:\IN\ED\Dat\AA\Cal\"
"C:\IN\ED\Dat\AB\Cal\"
"C:\IN\ED\Dat\AK\Cal\"
```

Second level:
- There will be a multiple files(number unknown) that will have the same fileType as the Variable in my list.  So it would look like (`C:\IN\ED\Dat\AA\Cal\testfile.AA`).  I need to be able to go through Each file in each folder and compare the last date modified to the strSourceFolders last date modified and if source is newer replace the rootfolders file.

So

```
If not strRootFolder & "*.AA" = strSourceFolder & "*.AA" Then
Copyfile strsourcefolder --->  strRootFolder
```